# Read text and match all dates in text file otherwise write value to error.txt file

Tags: vbscript

The below .TXT file is  read into a VBS FileSystemObject. I am trying to search for all dates that match otherwise I need to put them in a "error.txt" file. However, when I run my code below it is always placing the matches in the error.txt file and not skipping the matching dates.

Why are the dates not matching?

**INPUT:**

```
"LIRRR 1M",.412900,02/08/2016
"LIRRR 3M",.222700,02/08/2016
"LIRRR 6M",.333200,02/08/2016
"LIRRR12M",1.1333300,02/08/2016
"FEDFRRRR",.333000,02/08/2016
"CCC 1YR",.550330,02/08/2016
"5YRCMT",1.2503300,02/08/2016
"10YRCMT",1.860000,02/08/2016
```

**Here is the code that I have written:**

```
On error resume next
Const ForReading = 1
Dim strSearchFor
Dim MyDate, MyWeekDay
MyDate = Date ' Assign a date.
MyWeekDay = Weekday(MyDate) 
If MyWeekDay = 2 then 
  strSearchFor =Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2)&"/"&Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date-3), 2)&"/"&DatePart("yyyy",Date)
 Else 
  strSearchFor =Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2)&"/"&Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date-1), 2)&"/"&DatePart("yyyy",Date)
 End If
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Desktop\index.txt", ForReading)
do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) <> 0 then

    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Desktop\pass.txt")
      objFile.Write "date is  match"& vbCrLf

    Else
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Desktop\error.txt")
      objFile.Write "date is not match"& vbCrLf
    End If
loop
objTextFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use RegEx to get the portion of the string that appears to be the date and use the [IsDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48y0723t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) Function to validate it?

```
Option Explicit
Dim arrLines,i
arrLines = ReadFile("./input.txt","byline")
For i=LBound(arrLines) to UBound(arrLines)
    wscript.echo FormatOutput(arrLines(i))
Next
'*********************************************
Function FormatOutput(s)
    Dim re, match
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "[\d]+[\/-][\d]+[\/-][\d]+"
    re.Global = True
    For Each match In re.Execute(s)
        if IsDate(match.value) then
            FormatOutput = CDate(match.value)
            Exit For
        end if
    Next
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
'*********************************************
Function ReadFile(path,mode)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim objFSO,objFile,i,strLine
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path,ForReading)
    If mode = "byline" then
        Dim arrFileLines()
        i = 0
        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
            strLine = objFile.ReadLine
            strLine = Trim(strLine)
            If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
                arrFileLines(i) = strLine
                i = i + 1
                ReadFile = arrFileLines
            End If  
        Loop
        objFile.Close
    End If
    If mode = "all" then
        ReadFile = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
    End If
End Function
'*****************************************************************
```

Comment: @Rand Don't forget to accept it as an anwser and upvote it !