# vbscript for each array

Tags: arrays, loops, vbscript

I'm looking to pull a text document or single field CSV document into an array then loop through the array.

I've been through a few examples on here but continue to fail to get the script working.

Any insight would be appreciated and sorry if I missed a previous useful posting.

```
    #$language = "VBScript"
#$interface = "1.0"

crt.Screen.Synchronous = True

Sub Main
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set hosts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\2016\3 SmartServices\SNMPHosts.txt")



Do Until hosts.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = hosts.Readline 
    arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , ",")   
Loop 

hosts.Close

For Each item In hosts
    crt.Screen.Send "telnet " & item & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "username: "
    crt.Screen.Send "UUUU" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "password: "
    crt.Screen.Send "PPPP" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString ">"
    crt.Screen.Send "en" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.Send "PPPP" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "#"
    crt.Screen.Send "conf t" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "(config)#"
    crt.Screen.Send "COMMAND STATIC TEXT" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.Send "COMMAND STATIC TEXT" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "(config)#"
    crt.Screen.Send "end" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "#"
    crt.Screen.Send "wr" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "#"
    crt.Screen.Send "exit" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "WAIT END STRING"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the format of your hosts file? What error message, if any, do you receive? "Not working" is no use as a problem description. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Edit your question and post your .csv data

Comment: You can also get inspired by this : [Function ReadFile(path,mode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299606/read-text-and-match-all-dates-in-text-file-otherwise-write-value-to-error-txt-fi?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split command is what you need. So `ReadAll` rather than `ReadLine`

```
MyVar = Split(hosts.ReadAll, vbcrlf)

For Each thing in MyVar
    Msgbox Replace(thing, ",", "")
Next
```

From Help at https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

> **Split Function**
>
> Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings.
>
> ```
> Split(expression[, delimiter[, count[, compare]]])
> ```

Use replace to remove the comma.

Comment: They're already using `Split()` problem is they are not doing correctly. Also using `Readline()` would be fine if they wanted to make sure that the commas were only read line by line into an array. Problem with `ReadAll()` method is it will also read in the Carriage Return + Linefeed at the end of each line in the CSV not to mention it's less efficient for larger files.

Comment: But it makes an array. Single field CSV don't have commas.

Comment: Fair point didn't notice the single field bit in the question, for a single line it should work fine. Also think you may have meant single field CSV don't have new lines not commas *(ofc they have commas it's a CSV)*.